# Existence of analytic function from A to B .

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Does there exists a non constant analytic map $f:A\to B$ . Where $A=\{z\in \mathbb C~:~ |z|\neq 0\}$ and $B=\{z \in \mathbb C ~:~ |z|>1\}$.
I am unable to construct one

Comment: @G.Sassatelli sorry i forgot to add non constant map

Comment: I thought so.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$